# GoLang postgres testcontainer convert BindMounts to Mounts

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, testcontainers

I have just upgraded the test container lib from `github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go v0.12.0` to `github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go v0.13.0`
previously this is the way I was creating a request

```
    ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
            Image:          mountebankImage,
            Name:           uuid.New().String(),
            ExposedPorts:   []string{mountebankExposedPort},
            BindMounts:     map[string]string{"/mountebank": path.Join(c.rootDir, "/test/stubs/mountebank")},
            Entrypoint:     []string{"mb", "start", "--configfile", "/mountebank/imposters.ejs"},
            Networks:       []string{c.network.Name},
```

In the recent version of the test container library, BindMounts(not supported anymore [link](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/blob/6b770200a5f777816d99189472166ccda72f47da/docker.go#L745)) got replaced by Mounts.
Tried replacing the same in my init script however not able to find it.

```
BindMounts:     map[string]string{"/mountebank": path.Join(c.rootDir, "/test/stubs/mountebank")},
```

its a part of request body. Tried with  `testcontainers.ContainerMounts{}`etc.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ContainerRequest`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go#ContainerRequest) object contains a list of [`ContainerMount`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go#ContainerMount) objects, which document that

> Source is typically either a GenericBindMountSource or a GenericVolumeMountSource

[`GenericBindMountSource`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go#GenericBindMountSource) just names a host path.  You could also use a [`DockerBindMountSource`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go#DockerBindMountSource) if you needed advanced options.

So you should be able to replace that `BindMounts:` parameter with `Mounts:`

```golang
ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Mounts: testcontainers.Mounts(testcontainers.ContainerMount{
                Source: testcontainers.GenericBindMountSource{
                        HostPath: path.Join(c.rootDir, "/test/stubs/mountebank"),
                },
                Target: testcontainers.ContainerMountTarget("/mountebank"),
        }),
        ...
},
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just a minor correction `Target: testcontainers.ContainerMountTarget("/mountebank"),` is redundant , instead of this we can directly use `Target: "/mountebank",`